# Macro resulting from evaluation of other macros not evaluated

Tags: boost, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I have a question about the way C preprocessor works. I've written the code below. When `OPREP(n)` is used it should result in something like this:
`OP(0,OP(1,OP(2,OP(3, .... OP(n,`. Then what I wanted to achieve is when I add something like `whatever)))))))` with `n` right parentheses, I should get
`OP(0,OP(1,OP(2,OP(3, .... OP(n,whatever)))))))` which should evaluate to
`0 1 2 3 4 5 .... n whatever`.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/comma.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/paren.hpp>

#define OP(a,b) a b
#define T0() OP
#define OPMAC(z,n,s) T0()BOOST_PP_LPAREN() n BOOST_PP_COMMA()
#define OPREP(n_) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n_, OPMAC, a)

OPREP(2) 3))
```

When I compile and look at the preprocessor output I get:
`OP( 0 , OP( 1 , 3))`. That is it didn't evaluate the resulting OP() macros.
My question is why, and how can I force it to be evaluated?

Comment: sound a bit like a XY problem to me; what do actually want to output? why would you want to manually type in the right half of the expression and generate the left part?

Comment: @m.s. This is a minimal example. In practice the macro `OP` takes 3 arguments - the running counter, text1 and text2. Both text1 and text2 of each nested OP invocation change extensively (hence I want to be able to edit them, and it's not just a single parameter `whatever` as in this example, but rather `n` different nested `whatever`s). While the right part doesn't change - it's just OP with a running counter. If n=20 it can be pretty annoying to write OP(0,OP(1,OP(2 20 times. I realize there can be other implementations. I can think of several. But I want to know why this one didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. To force another evaluation all I need to do is add a dummy `FORCE_EVAL` macro that evaluates to the same thing as its parameters and enclose my call in it:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/comma.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/paren.hpp>

#define OP(a,b) a b
#define T0() OP
#define OPMAC(z,n,s) T0()BOOST_PP_LPAREN() n BOOST_PP_COMMA()
#define OPREP(n_) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n_, OPMAC, a)
#define FORCE_EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__

FORCE_EVAL(OPREP(2) 3)))
```